# Image not displaying using Craft CMS

Tags: twig, craftcms

I'm new to using Craft CMS and trying to successfully make an image display.

I have set up a field with the handle `heroImage` and this is the code I have within the template.

```
{% set image = entry.heroImage.one() %}

<div>
<img src="{{ image.getUrl }}">
</div>
```

However, the image is not displaying in the browser.

Comment: What does `{{ dump(image) }}` output?

Comment: @DarkBee it outputs a bunch of code instead of the image itself.

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: @DarkBee I managed to solve the issue, the ASSET_BASE_URL was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add parenthesis after getUrl as it was a function (method). You can use below code for that.

```
{% set image = entry.heroImage.one() %}
<div>
<img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Users encountering this may want to check folder permissions. I encountered this in a site migration situation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  <img src="https://dev-craft3-384fa3039dfb.hyperlane.co/uploads/scren1.png" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" alt="ALI TEST LIVE LINK" />
```